# sort_values,TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'numpy.ndarray' and 'str'

Tags: python, pandas

My data set

```
Mimi: 47.20
Marko: 51.14
Shellie: 49.95
Lopes: 48.80
Jack: 46.60
Neli: 52.70
Martin: 57.65
Jessi: 55.45
Adri: 52.30
Lia: 59.90
```

My code

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('laptimes.txt', sep=":", header = None)
print (df)
newdata = df.sort_values(by=1, axis=1, ascending=True)
print (newdata)
```

But I got this

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "o4.py", line 4, in <module>
    newdata = df.sort_values(by=1, axis=1, ascending=True)
  File "/home/milenko/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 3299, in sort_values
    na_position=na_position)
  File "/home/milenko/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/sorting.py", line 247, in nargsort
    indexer = non_nan_idx[non_nans.argsort(kind=kind)]
TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'numpy.ndarray' and 'str'
```

What I really wanted was to sort values in column 1. What should I do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you need `axis=0`, for sort by column, what is default parameter, so can be omit. Also `ascending=True` too:

```
newdata = df.sort_values(by=1)
```

`axis=1` is used for sort per row:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({0: [7, 2], 1: [3, 5], 2: [4, 8]})
print (df)
   0  1  2
0  7  3  4
1  2  5  8

#sort by first row 0
print (df.sort_values(by=0, axis=1))
   1  2  0
0  3  4  7
1  5  8  2

#sort by first column 0
print (df.sort_values(by=0, axis=0))
   0  1  2
1  2  5  8
0  7  3  4

#sort by first column 0
print (df.sort_values(by=0))
   0  1  2
1  2  5  8
0  7  3  4
```

Comment: Super, glad can help. Nice weekend!